# Options to increase network lattency

Tags: router, latency

I need to permanently increase network latency in approximately 100ms, without losing packets.

Reason: On a certain server and internet game my ping is too much lower than the other people playing it. I have 15ms, when average is 150ms which gives me cheater-like advantages.

So also out of curiosity I'm looking for ways to increase my ping while keeping connection stable. What are my options if any?

I thought about VPN services, but it seems like a bad option since games use UDP?

Is there any router/software that would assist me on this?